# Grouping by each value in a column of a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I have a dataframe with 7 columns, as follows:

```
Bank Name | Number | Firstname | Lastname | ID | Date1    | Date2
B1        | 1      | ABC       | EFG      | 12 | Somedate | Somedate
B2        | 2      | ABC       | EFG      | 12 | Somedate | Somedate
B1        | 1      | DEF       | EFG      | 12 | Somedate | Somedate
B3        | 3      | ABC       | GHI      | 13 | Somedate | Somedate
B4        | 4      | XYZ       | FHJ      | 13 | Somedate | Somedate
B5        | 5      | XYZ       | DFI      | 13 | Somedate | Somedate
```

I want to create a tuple with 4 elements for each `ID`, such that each tuple element represents `(Bank Name, Number, Firstname, Lastname)` for each `ID` and the values of these tuple elements is the count of the distinct elements present in that respective column for that ID.
For eg: For `ID = 12`, the tuple should be `(2, 2, 2, 1)` and for `ID=13,` the tuple should be `(3, 3, 2, 3)`

I'm able to get all rows for a particular ID by doing the following:

```
print(df.loc[df['ID'] == '12'])
```

But, I do not know how to do this for each value in the ID column (much like the group by clause in SQL, and also get the count instead of the actual values in the rows.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `apply` you could do

```
In [117]: cols = ['BankName', 'Number', 'Firstname', 'Lastname']

In [126]: df.groupby('ID')[cols].nunique().apply(tuple, axis=1)
Out[126]:
ID
12    (2, 2, 2, 1)
13    (3, 3, 2, 3)
dtype: object
```

or,

```
In [127]: df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: tuple(x[c].nunique() for c in cols))
Out[127]:
ID
12    (2, 2, 2, 1)
13    (3, 3, 2, 3)
dtype: object
```

Or, if you want as dataframe instead of tuple

```
In [122]: df.groupby('ID').agg({c: 'nunique' for c in cols})
Out[122]:
    Lastname  Number  Firstname  BankName
ID
12         1       2          2         2
13         3       3          2         3

or,

In [123]: df.groupby('ID')[cols].nunique()
Out[123]:
    BankName  Number  Firstname  Lastname
ID
12         2       2          2         1
13         3       3          2         3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Used the second one. The first one gives AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'nunique' error.

Comment: What's your `pd.__version__`?

Comment: Version '0.19.2'

Comment: Instead of just having the count for the 'Number' in the second element of the tuple, is it possible to have something like: Eg, for ID 12: (2, {1:2, 2:1}, 2, 1), where the keys in the inner dictionary represent the 'Number' and their value is the number of times that 'Number' comes for that particular ID.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and lambda function with [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html):

```
cols = ['Bank Name', 'Number', 'Firstname', 'Lastname']
df = df.groupby('ID')[cols].apply(lambda x: tuple(x.nunique()))
print (df)
ID
12    (2, 2, 2, 1)
13    (3, 3, 2, 3)
dtype: object
```

And if necessary converting to `dict`:

```
d = df.groupby('ID')[cols].apply(lambda x: tuple(x.nunique())).to_dict()
print (d)
{12: (2, 2, 2, 1), 13: (3, 3, 2, 3)}
```

Comment: After converting to dict,  
Instead of just having the count for the 'Number' in the second element of the tuple, is it possible to have something like: Eg, for ID 12: (2, {1:2, 2:1}, 2, 1), where the keys in the inner dictionary represent the 'Number' and their value is the number of times that 'Number' comes for that particular ID.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:

```
group = df.groupby('ID')['Bank Name','Number','Firstname','Lastname'].nunique()
group['tuples'] = group.apply(lambda x: tuple(x), axis=1)
group.loc[:,'tuples']
```

The output will be:

```
ID
12    (2, 2, 2, 1)
13    (3, 3, 2, 3)
Name: tuples, dtype: object
```